# Depth to World Coordinates transformation using OpenN and KinectI

Tags: c++, kinect, openni

I have a question about how to interpret the results given by the transformation from depth to real world coordinates using the Microsoft Kinect Sensor and OpenNI. Using Visual Studio 2015 C++ , OpenNI 2.0 and OpenCV 2.4

The library works fine , and i'm able to get the depth map and then use the "openni::CoordinateConverter::convertDepthToWorld" in a specific pixel and get its x,y,z world coordinates.

What is confusing is when i pick two pixels and get the x distance between (horizontal distance) them , the value is different depending on the depth of these pixels.
For example , I'm pointing the Kinect sensor to solid wall , and i market two reference points on it. Then i go to the depth view of the Kinect and i localize these two points (pixel location) and i extract the x,y,z coordinates. However , the x distance between these two points if the Kinect Sensor is 700mm from the wall is different from the value if i put the Kinect 1000mm from the wall.

So the question is , is that correct that the distance between two fixed points in the world change together with the depth ? I was expecting the distance between then to be the same , when i move the sensor forward or backward (to the wall).

Thanks.

---

```
try {
    openni::OpenNI::initialize();

    openni::Device device;
    auto ret = device.open(openni::ANY_DEVICE);
    if (ret != openni::STATUS_OK) {
        throw std::runtime_error("");
    }

    openni::VideoStream depthStream;
    depthStream.create(device, openni::SensorType::SENSOR_DEPTH);
    depthStream.start();



    openni::VideoStream colorStream;
    colorStream.create(device, openni::SensorType::SENSOR_COLOR);
    colorStream.start();


    device.setDepthColorSyncEnabled(true);
    device.setImageRegistrationMode(openni::IMAGE_REGISTRATION_DEPTH_TO_COLOR);

    cv::Mat depthImage;
    cv::Mat colorImage;
    cv::Mat dst_image;

    float error;




    cv::Mat ColorFrame;



    while (1) {

        // Grab Frames
        openni::VideoFrameRef depthFrame;
        depthStream.readFrame(&depthFrame);

        openni::VideoFrameRef initialcolorFrame;
        colorStream.readFrame(&initialcolorFrame);

      // Create a RGB frame from the Color Stream frame

        const openni::RGB888Pixel* imageBuffer = (const openni::RGB888Pixel*)initialcolorFrame.getData();

        ColorFrame.create(initialcolorFrame.getHeight(), initialcolorFrame.getWidth(), CV_8UC3);
        memcpy(ColorFrame.data, imageBuffer, 3 * initialcolorFrame.getHeight()*initialcolorFrame.getWidth() * sizeof(uint8_t));

        cv::cvtColor(ColorFrame, ColorFrame, CV_BGR2RGB); //this will put colors right



        if (depthFrame.isValid()) {

                depthImage = cv::Mat(depthStream.getVideoMode().getResolutionY(),depthStream.getVideoMode().getResolutionX(),
                CV_16U, (char*)depthFrame.getData());

        }




    //Get World Coordinates of two points.
        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;
        float z = 0;

        float xx = 0;
        float yy = 0;
        float zz = 0;



        //Point 1 ( camera image center )
       openni::CoordinateConverter::convertDepthToWorld(depthStream, 320, 240, depthImage.at<openni::DepthPixel>(320, 240),&x,&y,&z);


        //Second point

        openni::CoordinateConverter::convertDepthToWorld(depthStream, 200, 220, depthImage.at<openni::DepthPixel>(200, 220), &xx, &yy, &zz);


    //Draw where these points are.

        cv::circle(ColorFrame, cv::Point(320, 240), 5, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), -1, CV_AA);
        cv::circle(ColorFrame, cv::Point(200, 220), 5, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1, CV_AA);



        // Get the depth of these two points
        auto videoMode = depthStream.getVideoMode();

        int centerX = 320;
        int centerY = 240;
        int centerXX = 200;
        int centerYY = 220;
        int centerIndexX = (centerY * videoMode.getResolutionX()) + centerX;
        int centerIndexXX = (centerYY * videoMode.getResolutionX()) + centerXX;



        short* depth = (short*)depthFrame.getData();


        //Write x,y,z world coordinates into the screen
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "CENTER :320, 240 :" << std::endl ;
        cv::putText(ColorFrame,
            ss.str(),
            cv::Point(0, 50),
            cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            1,
            cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0),
            1);

        std::stringstream ss2;
        ss2 << "x[mm] :" << x << " y[mm] :" << y << " z[mm] :" << depth[centerIndexX];

        cv::putText(ColorFrame,
            ss2.str(),
            cv::Point(0, 100),
            cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            0.8,
            cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255),
            1);




        std::stringstream ss3;
        ss3 << "Green Point: 200, 220 :" << std::endl;
        cv::putText(ColorFrame,
            ss3.str(),
            cv::Point(0, 150),
            cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            1.0,
            cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0),
            1);

        std::stringstream ss4;
        ss4 << "x[mm] :" << xx << " y[mm] :" << yy << " z[mm] :" << depth[centerIndexXX];

        cv::putText(ColorFrame,
            ss4.str(),
            cv::Point(0, 200),
            cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            0.8,
            cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0),
            1);


        cv::imshow("Depth Camera", dst_image);
        cv::imshow("RGB Camera", ColorFrame);



        int key = cv::waitKey(10);
        if (key == 'q') {
            break;
        }
    }
}
catch (std::exception&) {
    std::cout << openni::OpenNI::getExtendedError() << std::endl;
}
```

}

Comment: How big is the difference? There is some sensor noise that will lead to slightly different results each time you measure your points. And this noise increases with distance. Give us some examples, so we can see if it's within the expected noise or if something else is at play.

Comment: For example starts with 150 mm , when i'm 700mm from the wall , if i move away from the wall , for example z=1000mm the distance increases to 190 mm. It's a big difference and i don't believe this is noise. I will post the cod in the post so you guys can see what is going on

Comment: I just observed that the x coordinate given by the ConvertDepthtoWorld is not right also. On the OpenNI dictionary says that the x axis of this system is along a line that passes through the infrared projector and CMOS imager of the camera. I put an object on the right side of the camera , approximately 40mm from the infrared projector and the x coordinate given is 273mm . I don't get what is this X distance , because there is no way to measure 273mm from any distance from the infrared projector

Comment: Wait, you are using the same pixel coordinates to get your 3D coordinates both at 700mm and 1000mm? Then of course the 3D coordinates will change. The pixels will point to different positions in the real world, so the distance will be different as well. Or did I misunderstand your code?

Comment: HenningJ actually you opened my eyes , thanks ! I'm analyzing the difference between the same two pixels on different conditions ( 700mm and 1000mm from the wall ). So , i believe that the difference between those pixels is not necessarily the same , the difference between two fixed objects that should be the same, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So, mark two points on your wall and depending on the distance of the camera to the wall, they wont be at the same pixels. Get the coordinates of those points and compare them.